# What would happen if signed DLL replaced with un-signed?

Tags: c#, dll, strong-named-key

We have a bunch of libraries that are strong-named and placed in the GAC. We are trying to get away from the practice. Here is the scenario I need to address at the moment.

I have a DLL (to replace and existing and signed one, same name and overall structure) which I cannot sign or strong name properly, as we cannot reproduce the key. I will recompile a component/code using the unsigned version and later deploy it with unsigned copy, using . If remove the signed copy from GAC, will the other components (who would use the same probing) consume the new one without recompile or still demand the signed version?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on how it was used and defined in the compiled code. However, you can disable strong name validaton, [you may want to look into it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2009/12/30/how-to-turn-off-strong-name-validation/).

Comment: Thank you. I think I've read that one before. I did forget to add, that it is preferable for us not to have to recompile the other components, unless there is no other way, or it is so convoluted that it becomes detrimental.

Comment: Probably nothing will happen, strong name validation is turned off in full trust mode since .NET 3.5SP1.  Gives you lots of time to recompile the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strong-name signatures are not validated when an assembly is loaded into a full-trust application domain. more information about this bypass feature can be found in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwb8f617(v=vs.110).aspx).Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. I think we've decided not to mess with existing assemblies and move away by creating assemblies with different names, slowly migrating. Water always flows where there is less resistance.